# IBM MobileFirst 7.1 - Calling adapters from their URL failing with global variables and setActiveUser()

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I have a very simple hybrid sample app which has 3 adapters.

1. submitAuthStep1(username, password)
2. submitAuthStep2(answer)
3. getSecretData()

Adapter 1 and 2 are using the "wl_unprotected" security test.
Adapter 3 is using "AuthRealm"

```
var userIdentity;

function onAuthRequired(headers, errorMessage){
    WL.Logger.warn(" in OAuth Reuired...");
    WL.Logger.debug(" in OAuth Reuired...");

    errorMessage = errorMessage ? errorMessage : null;
    WL.Logger.debug(" in OAuth Reuired errorMessage..."+errorMessage);
    return {
        authRequired: true,
        authStep: 1,
        errorMessage: errorMessage
    };
}

function submitAuthStep1(username, password){
    if (username === "wl" && password === "wl"){
        WL.Logger.debug("Step 1 :: SUCCESS");
        userIdentity = {
                userId: username,
                displayName: username, 
                attributes: {}
        };

        return {
            authRequired: true,
            authStep: 2,
            question: "What is your pet's name?",
            errorMessage : ""
        };

    }

    else{
        WL.Logger.debug("Step 1 :: FAILURE");
        return onAuthRequired(null, "Invalid login credentials");
    }
}

function submitAuthStep2(answer){
    if (answer === "wl2"){
        WL.Logger.debug("Step 2 :: SUCCESS");
        WL.Server.setActiveUser("AuthRealm", userIdentity);
        WL.Logger.debug("Authorized access granted");

        return {
            authRequired: false
        };
    }

    else{
        WL.Logger.debug("Step 2 :: FAILURE");
        return onAuthRequired(null, "Wrong security question answer");
    }

}

function getSecretData(){
    /*return {
        secretData: "A very very very very secret data"
    };*/
    WL.Logger.info(" Active User INfo "+JSON.stringify(WL.Server.getActiveUser("AuthRealm")));
    WL.Logger.info(" .... User INfo "+ WL.Server.getClientRequest().getSession().getAttribute("AuthRealm"));

    return userIdentity;
}

function onLogout(){
    userIdentity = null;
    WL.Server.setActiveUser("AuthRealm", userIdentity);
    WL.Logger.debug("Logged out");
}

function signOut(){
    userIdentity = null;
    WL.Server.setActiveUser("AuthRealm", userIdentity);
    WL.Logger.debug("Logged out");
}
```

When invoking this code with the hybrid application it works fine, when I try to test and invoke these adapters using eclipse (Call MobileFirst Adapter option) submitAuthStep1 works, then when I get to submitAuthStep2 my global variable 'userIdentity' is gone. I have also tried to invoke the adapters in sequence using their corresponding URL's in a chrome browser tab with the same result!

worklight.properties is using session dependence

```
mfp.session.independent=false
mfp.attrStore.type=httpsession
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Does it work outside of Studio?

Comment: @IdanAdar I don't have access to MobileFirst Studio just eclipse and browsers. The only time this code works as expected is when I use it as the application preview in a web browser. Is there some other method I could test this out?

Comment: What are you talking about... how are you previewing this in eclipse if you're not using the Studio plug-in, for Eclipse? I am saying, you need to test if it is failing in devices - your one and true test for your application.

Comment: @IdanAdar Yes, I am using the plugin with eclipse. I will test it with a real device. When it fails though, is there some other settings or known issues when invoking adapters directly that could cause this?

Comment: I am sorry to say dude ,here global variable is  meant to be per user .you can't use global variable . You can make this more complex if you are going to use this as a data store, but the same idea goes. Say, you have a dictionary to store your global data. otherwise  global variable 'userIdentity' is gone.

Comment: @NazmulHasan it's not so much the global variable, this was just whipped up quickly for testing. I do know what you are saying though. These problems don't manifest themselves on iOS devices, just windows and Android. I just can't understand how previewing the application allows this to work but calling the adapters from their URL or through eclipse fails. On iOS they dont fail with this method of testing either. Physical Android devices also fail but not iOS devices. It's like the session is getting lost somewhere during use. I think the setActiveUser() stems from this problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

The "Call Adapter" feature of the MobileFirst Studio cannot be used to test authentication and security. The way it works, it gets direct access to the resource and skips all of the MobileFirst security framework. It is meant to test regular adapters.

Same thing if you try to get to the adapter directly from the browser.

You have no MobileFirst session, therefore you start fresh for every request. Global variables won't be carried on to the next request.

You can only test authentication and security features using an application.